# How I can stop Excel restarting itself every time I close it?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, office365

I am developing a Windows application which integrates with Microsoft Excel, including via a COM add-in. This means I regularly make code changes (in Visual Studio) and then restart Excel to test the changes to the add-in.

**When I close Excel, Excel decides to restart itself of its own accord**. This happens more or less every time, unless I close it without opening a workbook.

This is *not* a problem with Excel *crashing* and restarting; on most occasions I close the Excel session cleanly. Ten seconds later, Excel restarts itself, which I do not want.

There are various related questions online troubleshooting lists online provided by Microsoft associates; none has helped. Most relate to scenarios where Excel is crashing, or recommend "one-time" fixes like clearing the XLSTART folder.

The reason this is so problematic is this:

- Often, after closing Excel, I want to make a tiny code change, rebuild my solution in Visual Studio and then restart Excel.
- Because this involves overwriting the add-in files, I can't do this while Excel is running. (I also cannot use 'hot reload' because of the way the application works.)
- I therefore have to wait for the new (unwanted) Excel session to start, then close it, then rebuild.
- Because the add-in is very complex, it takes 20-30 seconds for Excel to load (with the add-in built in Debug mode - much faster in Release mode, but I need Debug mode).
- This means I waste around a minute *every single time I test any code change*, which is becoming intolerable.

During intensive development, this is probably costing me around an hour a day, which is absolutely ridiculous.

Q1: **Can anyone help me stop this nonsense?**

Q2: Has this immediate automated restart feature ever been useful to anyone, ever? (I don't really need to know the answer to this, but if anyone answers 'yes' it might perhaps help me feel a little less infuriated about the situation.)

I am running:

- Windows 11 Home edition (10.0.22621)
- Microsoft 365 Apps for business (desktop edition)
- Microsoft Excel for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2306 Build 16.0.16529.20164) 64-bit
- Visual Studio 2022, Professional edition, version 17.2.1

Comment: Why do you think that Excel has an immediate automated restart feature? I would think that your software might have more to do with the problem.

Comment: @harrymc - it is clear from other answers online to similar questions that this is a feature of Excel, presumably intended to "recover" after Excel thinks it has not closed correctly. My software is definitely not asking Excel to restart, but something is - presumably some monitoring tool that's part of the Microsoft 365 installation. All I want to do is stop Excel from starting (ever) unless I ask it to. This shouldn't be difficult and certainly shouldn't be impossible!

Comment: Does it happen in Excel without your software ?

Comment: I haven't noticed (since I hardly ever close Excel otherwise, unless restarting my machine). But this really shouldn't matter. I am quite prepared to believe that something in my add-in, or the fact that Excel is being started by Visual Studio, or something else development-related, is causing Excel to think it "needs to restart" after I close it. But I don't want that to happen, whatever the reason for Excel deciding to do it - whether it's my software, a third-party add-in, a corrupted workbook or Venus entering Libra. *No* other application does this.

Comment: Without testing Excel without your software, we won't know if your software is responsible. Plus do this test.

Comment: It is hard to be sure, because the behaviour seems non-deterministic. I haven't yet triggered it without my COM add-in present, and I *think* a rebuild in Visual Studio (including re-registration of the add-in) increases the likelihood. I accept I could try to debug this to isolate the exact cause, but that might not help. Suppose the "cause" is that rebuilding my software overwrites some registry value which makes Excel decide it needs to restart when it next closes. I can't avoid writing the add-in's registry values, but the subsequent restart is an Excel-ism that I simply want to stop.